# Flutter save shared preferences of multiple users

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have two types of settings which I want to save on the users apps device. First is filter settings, second is if user is opening the app the very first time.

For filter I have multiple bools to save, for the first open app value I just need a single bool. Now my problem is if I log into the app with another account, the values of the first account are choosen. I need to make a set for each account, but I dont know how, since im changing single values all the time.

these are my functions for getting and setting a filter:

```
    void putShared(String key, bool val) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool(key, val);
}

Future getShared(String key) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  bool val = prefs.getBool(key) == null ? false : (prefs.getBool(key));
  return val;
}
```

So how to change the code to make it work for multiple accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a unique user id as a prefix to all the keys. Like..

```
    void putShared(String key, bool val) async {

      String userSpecificKey = userID + key;

      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      prefs.setBool(userSpecificKey, val);
    }
    

    Future getShared(String key) async {

      String userSpecificKey = userID + key;

      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      bool val = prefs.getBool(userSpecificKey) == null ? false : (prefs.getBool(userSpecificKey));
      return val;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is while saving the values in the sharedprefrences you rather use a map where the key must be unique like id and value of what you need. Then just encode the map which will convert it to string and then you can save it as string in sharedPrefrences and then when you retrive you just decode the map and just check if the loggedin user id matches the id which you have logged in if not do not fetch the values else fetch them.

Comment: this seems to be a great suggestion to me. thank you! could you provide me an example for this? you can just user hard coded values for the identification, i just need to see how the function looks like with encoding/decoding and with map

Comment: Yes I am a bit busy but I will provide you the example.