# How to save shared Preferences for different users? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have a `List<String>` which saves names of categories using shared preferences.

I did everything right but the problem is that every user should have his own categories that he created, if he didn't create anything.. just show default categories not other users categories.

Default categories :

```
List<String> defaultCategories = [ "Health", "Finance", "Tech"];
```

Let's say now User A logged in and what he will see is the default categories, he can add to them remove them and that's just fine.. Let's say he added one new category, so he will see it and will be saved in shared preferences and that's good.

User A signs out and then sign in and everything is as he left.. that's great!

Now, when a User B login.. guess what he sees? User A categories!! that's the problem.

I want User B to see default categories if he didn't change anything or sees his own categories.

Can anyone help me in that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter save shared preferences of multiple users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709149/flutter-save-shared-preferences-of-multiple-users)

Comment: I will check that

Comment: Unfourtnately, no.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it multiple ways, and all of them correct so you must just choose one of them.

Ex you can do with these steps;
1.You can cache the default list with a general key in shared preferences.
2.You can add a category list for your user model(nullable),
3.You can save the your user model to your shared preferences with the users unique id.

In this way you can retrive your users category list from shared preferences.
In this way you can retrive default category list from shared preferences.

How can you determine to your user category list?

You can just call the below getter in your view model, controller or where are you needing.

```
bool get hasUserCategories=>usermodel.categories!= null && usermodel.categories!.isNotEmpty;
```

Comment: Thank you but I now tried a solution that works only when I run app from main. When I log out and log back in again it keeps the previous data unless I run it from main>